# Import vcard in Windows Phone device

Tags: windows-phone-8, contacts, vcf-vcard

The short question is how to import a contact with three emails into windows phone ?

More detailed: I have bellow vcard (.vcf) file

BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:3.0

N;CHARSET=utf-8:;Byron

FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:Byron

UID;CHARSET=UTF-8:Byron

TEL;TYPE=CELL:111

TEL;TYPE=CELL:2222

TEL;TYPE=HOME:33333

TEL;TYPE=HOME:44444

TEL;TYPE=WORK:555555

TEL;TYPE=WORK:66666

TEL;TYPE=COMPANY:7777

TEL;TYPE=PAGER:88888

TEL;TYPE=HOME;TYPE=FAX:99999

TEL;TYPE=WORK;TYPE=FAX:1010101010101010101010

EMAIL;TYPE=PERSONAL:byrPersonal@gmail.com

EMAIL;TYPE=WORK:byrWork@gmail.com

EMAIL;TYPE=OTHER:otherByron@gmail.com

REV:6/6/2014 4:56:01 am

END:VCARD

I am using ContactInformation.ParseVcardAsync method and then saving with phoneContact.SaveAsync method. I can import the contacts in both the emulator and the device. My problem is i can't get all emails in the device. The last email **EMAIL;TYPE=OTHER:otherByron@gmail.com** is not visible in the device but it is visible in the emulator. 
OS Version emulator:8.0.9903.10
OS Version device: 8.0.10521.155

Any help?